# Eureka discovery and web service communication using self signed certificate & https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a web service and eureka discovery implemented. My objective is to enhance security using https with a self signed certificate.

For simplicity, my certicates are : eureka and client.

**I generated certicates using the following command line:**

```
keytool -genkey -alias eureka -keyalg RSA -keysize 3072 -keystore eureka.jks -validity 3650 -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1"
```

And:

```
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keysize 3072 -keystore client.jks -validity 3650 -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1"
```

I obtain 2 jks files.

**I Export certificates from generated keystores for both client and server sides: **

```
keytool -export -alias client -file client.crt -keystore client.jks
keytool -export -alias eureka -file eureka.crt -keystore eureka.jks
```

I have now 2 more files crt.

After this: I import client's certficate to server's keystore and server's certficate to client's keystore.

```
keytool -import -alias client -file client.crt -keystore eureka.jks
keytool -import -alias eureka -file eureka.crt -keystore client.jks
```

Finally, I imported the JKS to PKCS12
We have to convert client’s keystore from JKS to PKCS12 format

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks -destkeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass 123456 -deststorepass 123456 -srcalias client -destalias client -srckeypass 123456 -destkeypass 123456 -noprompt
```

**I also added the following content to eureka server application.properties:**

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=eureka-discovery

# SSL configuration with self signed certificate
server.ssl.enabled=true
#server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certs/eureka.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=eureka

server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:certs/eureka.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store-password=123456
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=0

eureka.instance.secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled=false
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/health
```

**On the client side, I have added the following content to application.properties :**

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users-ws

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certs/client.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=client

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761
eureka.instance.nonSecurePortEnabled=false
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true
eureka.instance.securePort=${server.port}
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https://localhost:${server.port}/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https://localhost:${server.port}/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https://localhost:${server.port}
#eureka.client.securePortEnabled=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.client.eureka-server-port}/eureka
```

**When running the applications I have errors on both sides**

In eureka server application:

```
Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='https://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information stacktrace=jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:661)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:413)
    ... 112 more

2024-01-18T02:20:57.058+01:00  WARN 50188 --- [eureka-discovery] [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
2024-01-18T02:20:57.059+01:00  INFO 50188 --- [eureka-discovery] [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EUREKA-DISCOVERY/Jupiter.home:eureka-discovery:8761 - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

On the client side I have the following stack trace:

```
2024-01-18 02:23:13 [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] WARN  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2024-01-18 02:23:13 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] WARN  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failed with message: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/USERS-WS": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2024-01-18 02:23:13 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] WARN  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_USERS-WS/Jupiter.home:users-ws:0 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2024-01-18 02:23:13 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] WARN  c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator - There was a problem with the instance info replicator
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:820)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

At this stage, Eureka is running but not discovering anything at all. My Web service is not able to register to Eureka too. What stage is actually missing for make the whole application work ? What configuration is missing ?

Comment: On Mobile. You need to either add the certificate to the jvm on the client or setup a new rest template bean and configure the certificate there.